# Retrieving actively used process with Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to build an activity monitor that tracks what program I have used.

Is there a command that retrieves the name of an active process? I am using Ubuntu, and unlike `top` which tells me all the process, I want the name of the process being `really used`, as in not in the background but I am clicking on them. Once I know which program it is, is there also a command that gives specifics such as meta-data to it?

Comment: This is likely something you can get from your window manager - or from X or Wayland. The term you probably want is 'focused window' - look at things like `xdotool` on the command line to see what's possible.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: I frequently have, say, an emacs window both foregrounded and focused, and a browser window that's in the background, but not blocked by anything, and still responding to trackpad swipes. If that's not a problem you're worried about, and you're happy reporting that only emacs is "active" at the moment, your life is a lot easier.

Comment: @match Yes, the term I was looking for was `focused window`. Found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25644/which-window-has-current-focus